# How to provide a valid crumb in ansible jenkins_script module

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am using Ansible to check the status of several jenkins servers. The playbook that I have created checks the disk space, uptime, and jenkins version perfectly fine. However, I tried to add a task that prints out a list of the installed jenkins plugins for each server by using the jenkins_Script module and keep receiving a '403' error message.

Playbook:

```
- name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
    jenkins_script:
      script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
      url: 'http://server.com:8080/'
      user: '*****'
      password: '*****'
```

Output:

```
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "args": null, 
        "force_basic_auth": true, 
        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
        "script": "println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)", 
        "url": "http://server.com:8080/", 
        "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
        "url_username": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
        "user": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
        "validate_certs": true
    }
}, 
"msg": "HTTP error 403 HTTP Error 403: No valid crumb was included in the request"
```

}

-- I believe I have narrowed down the issue - It looks like I wasn't providing a crumb. I have since generated the crumb, but there is no 'crumb' arguement for the jenkins_script module. Does anyone know how to successfully provide a crumb?

Will gladly clarify anything stated above if needed, and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/20207

-- if you're on ansible 2.3 the changes have already been committed all you have to do is make sure 'cross site request forgery' is enabled on the jenkins servers. (Manage jenkins > Configure Global security)